# Инициализатор типа "Emgu.CV.CvInvoke" выдал исключение

Tags: c#, emgu, исключения

Доброго всем времени суток!

Задался целью получить изображение со встроенной вебкамеры ноутбука. Нашел в интернете библиотеку EMGU CV, посмотрел примеры, использование и все дела. Начал пытаться юзать самостоятельно, но уже дня два немогу разобраться.

Проблема заключается в следующем:

коротенький код моей програмки

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.Util;

namespace CameraCapture
{
    public partial class CaptureForm : Form
    {
        private Capture capture = null;
        public CaptureForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                capture = new Capture();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

отказывается работать - выдает исключение уже в классе Capture.cs (класс принадлежит библиотеке EMGU.CV):

[image]

В библиотеке EMGU рассматривается пример, где используется захват камеры. Если я копирую оттуда код в свой созданный проект, то он отказывается работать по таким же причинам. Однако если открою проект примера, то все заработает идеально.

Помогите пожалуйста узнать в чем причина исключения и исправить ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Вы, судя по всему, не копируете `native dll'ки` в `Output Folder` (типа `opencv_core231.dll`). `EmguCV` —  это обертка над `OpenCV,` поэтому библиотеки `OpenCV` необходимы для ее работы.

> - В примерах от `EmguCV` это действие наверняка каким-либо способом автоматизировано.
> - Можете сделать это самостоятельно или прописать это действие в `Post-Build Events` (в том случае, если используется `Visual Studio`)`.`

- См. также **http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2910**

Comment: Спасибо большое. Добавил к проекту .dll-ки opencv и все заработало!)

Answer (score 2):

Убедитесь, что библиотечки OpenCV (cv100.dll, cxcore100.dll, cvaux100.dll, highgui100.dll) кладутся в папку с вашей программой. Посмотрите, как это сделано в тестовом проекте.

[Подробности тут (на английском)](http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=55&p=232#p232).

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку! она мне тоже очень помогла!)